# System.BadImageFormatException - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

Unable to resolve the exception. Already tried **clean rebuild**, also cleared  Temporary cache. Nothing worked!

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\385841ab\41679b95\App_global.asax.wuryexuy.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Stack Trace:

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\385841ab\41679b95\App_global.asax.wuryexuy.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +234
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity) +64
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults.get_CompiledAssembly() +116
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +82
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +22
   System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +12188385
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +52
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +335

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\385841ab\41679b95\App_global.asax.wuryexuy.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +73
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +668
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +39
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +749

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\385841ab\41679b95\App_global.asax.wuryexuy.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +716
```